# How to fix a goto problem in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I started learning programming a few days ago, and here i am with my first problems. I'm learning something about batch, but there is something in my code that is wrong, can you help me with this?

Specifically, the "goto" command it's not a go to. i've tried to put it in a single line, but it's like the goto doesn't exist. how can i fix it?

```
@echo off
:INIZIO
set /p "risp=Scegli un pokemon tra: Pikachu, Charizard e Blastoid:"
if [%risp%]=="pikachu" goto UNO
if [%risp%]=="charizard" goto UNO
if [%risp%]=="blastoid" goto UNO
:UNO
echo Bella scelta!
echo Vuoi attaccare o fuggire?
set/P risp= 
if [%risp%]=="attaccare" goto battaglia 1 
if [%risp%]=="fuggire" goto perdita
set/P risp=
:battaglia 1
echo e allora combattiamo!
echo Vuoi fare un attacco leggero o pesante?
set/P risp=
if [%risp%]==[leggero] echo il nemico sopravvive! ti attacca e il tuo pokemon muore! 
goto morte
if [%risp%]==[pesante] echo È superefficace, il pokèmon muore qui davanti!
goto win
:morte
set /p "risp=Continuare?
if [%risp%]=="si" echo e allora andiamo!
goto replay
if [%risp%]=="no" echo hai fallito la tua missione!
goto lose
:replay
set /p "risp=Scegli un pokemon tra:onix e reshiram:"
if [%risp%]=="onix" goto DUE 
if [%risp%]=="reshiram" goto DUE
:DUE
echo Vuoi attaccare o fuggire?
set /p "risp=
if [%risp%]==[attaccare] echo e allora combattiamo!
goto battaglia 2
if [%risp%]==[fuggire] echo sei riuscito a fuggire correndo all'impazzata
:battaglia 2
echo Vuoi fare un attacco leggero o pesante?
set /p "risp=
if [%risp%]==[pesante] echo È superefficace, il pokèmon muore qui davanti!
goto win
if [%risp%]==[leggero] echo il nemico non muore, ma la sua mossa non ti sfiora neanche
goto battaglia 2
:win
echo congratulazioni, hai vinto la tua prima battaglia!
pause
:perdita
echo sei scappato, ma non è ancora finita per te. preparati ad altri combattimenti in futuro!
```

I hope you can help me with this goto,but i need to learn much more about programming. thanks for the help!

Comment: Please change the label-names to remove spaces (put `_`). Take a look at How to create a [mcve]

Comment: See [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) and use command `choice` instead of `set /P`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information I think your problem are not `goto` commands but `if` conditionals

Suppose the user types `pikachu` on the first prompt. When the first `if` is reached the batch's parser will replace the variable read operation `%risp%` with the value inside the variable. So, your line

```cmd
if [%risp%]=="pikachu" goto UNO
```

is executed as

```cmd
if [pikachu]=="pikachu" goto UNO
```

You can see that `[pikachu]` is not equal to `"pikachu"` so the `goto` is not executed.

Some of your conditions are written as

```cmd
if [%risp%]==[leggero]
```

In those cases the condition will work as the line will be parsed into

```cmd
if [leggero]==[leggero]
```

but if the value retrieved from the user contains spaces the command will fail. This also needs to be changed.

Try with

```cmd
if "%risp%"=="pikachu" goto UNO
```

That is, quoted values on both sides of the condition (so both sides can be equal), with the quotes protecting the presence of spaces.

This (or similar) change should be made in all your `if` commands.

Another problem with your `goto`s is how you name the labels where to jump. You can not include spaces in the label name. `battaglia 1` and `battaglia 2` are seen as `battaglia` and the `goto` command will jump to the nearest (from `goto` line to end of file, then from start of file) matching label.